# Reducing two tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, reduce

I have two tensors.

1. A tensor [image: \sum_{n=1}^N] of shape (1,N)
2. A tensor [image: \sum_{n=1}^N] of shape (N,T)

What I want to calculate is the following scalar:

[image: \sum_{n=1}^N]

`tf.reduce_sum` seemed helpful, but I couldn't get my head around combining the two tensors and reduce functions to get what I want. Can someone help me how to write the above equation in `tensorflow`?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want this to be a one-liner?

Comment: Not necessarily. It doesn't have to be "one reduce function". I'll edit that part. Any solution is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N = 10
T = 20
l = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1, N), dtype=tf.float32)
z = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N, T), dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # swap axis for broadcasting to work
    l = tf.transpose(l, [1, 0])
    z_div_l = tf.divide(z, l)
    z_div_l_2 = tf.divide(1.0 - z, 1.0 - l)
    result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(z_div_l, z_div_l_2), axis=0)
    eval_result = sess.run(result)
    print('{}\n{}'.format(eval_result.shape, eval_result))
```

This calculates the above expression for every `t` from 0 to T-1, so it is not a scalar but a vector of size `(T,)`. Your question mentions you want to compute just one scalar, but the sum is only over `N` and not over `T`, so I assumed you just want this expression to be evaluated for every `t`.